# Are there alternatives to UNION for selecting the same columns from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax, wildcard

I've got 4-5 tables that have near identical names and I need to select columns which have the same names from them. So far I'm doing this:

```
    SELECT colA, colB FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT colA, colB FROM Table2
    UNION
    etc...
```

It seems like it could be overly verbose if you had more than a handful of similar tables and was wondering if there's any alternative syntax. Ideally I'd like something wildcard-y, like

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM Table%
```

If there is no alternative to `UNION`, why not? Is there a specific reason for not allowing this? I would imagine it's because SQL should be as specific as possible when it comes to the table definitions (table + col names, types, etc) while allowing flexibility in data manipulation (hence we have wildcards for the rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no alternative I could think of. If I were nitpicky, I'd say that if you have similar tables that contain similar data, you should reconsider your database design :-)

Comment: I had the same thought, but it's not _my_ design :) They're localised tables (e.g., TableUK, TableUSA, TableJapan) that have a lot of data coming in every day, so they were split off. Apparently this makes the whole process faster compared to one massive table. I just hope they don't add any more tables soon, though!

Comment: @Alex: should be one partitioned table maybe?

Comment: You may also create a view with an additional column "Country". But then the `UNION`s would go into the code for the view...

Answer (score 1):

No alternate for the UNION query developed by the database provider.

Answer (score 0):

you can use table aliases.
for instance:

```
select a.colA, b.colA, a.colB, b.colB
from table1 a
```

Comment: That would work if he didn't want each row from each table to be a single row in the result set. You're creating columns.

Comment: in that case sql server has something called 'transpose' this turns rows into colums.